# How to extract the first part of URL out using pig

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I have many long strings and part of the string contains url. I want to extract the first part of the url after https? before abcd.com out. Some url use http some use https; For example:

```
long string --------&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.abcd.com%2f------long string
long string --------&url=https%3a%2f%2fmobile.abcd.com%2f------long string
long string --------&url=http%3a%2f%2fmobile.abcd.com%2f------long string
long string --------&url=https%3a%2f%2faccount.abcd.com%2f------long string
long string --------&url=http%3a%2f%2fsale.abcd.com%2f------long string
long string --------&url=https%3a%2f%2flogin.abcd.com%2f------long string
```

The result will be www, mobile, mobile, account, sale, login.

What I've tried so far is

```
A = LOAD DATA; 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (chararray)REGEX_EXTRACT(line, '.*&url=https?%3a%2f%2f([^\.]+)\.', 1) AS firstparturl; 
DUMP B;
```

It's giving me an error complaining about the last period in the regex_extract ''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<=https?%3a%2f%2f)\w+(?=\.\w+\.\w+)`

Uses positive lookbehind to ensure it starts with

`http://`

then grabs whatever is there, checking with a lookahead that it must end in

`.<word>.<word>`

Because it's using lookahead/behind, those groups aren't captured, and the  default capture group is the answer you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (chararray)REGEX_EXTRACT(line, '.*&url=https?%3a%2f%2f([^.]+)\\.', 1) AS firstparturl;
```